# Problems following android hello-world tutorial

Tags: android

I am following this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

and I am at the "install a platform" part.

After I go to Android SDK and AVD Manager, choose Available Packages in the left panel, and on the right panel, I expand the Android Repository list to display the components available for installation.

Once I check the checkbox for "Android Repository" It shows me 2 options:
1) Android SDK tools, revision 15
2) Android SDK platform-tools revision 9

Naturally I have no idea which I need, so I check both :)
(Which should I choose and what are these options?)

Then I choose "install" and it stops in the middle with a warning "folder failed to be moved blah blah" - but I already ran it as administrator.

Then it ends up outputting this stuff:

```
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 9
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 9
'adb kill-server' succeeded.
Failed to rename directory C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Failed to rename directory C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Failed to rename directory C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Failed to rename directory C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Failed to rename directory C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Failed to rename directory C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Failed to rename directory C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
Skipping 'Android SDK Tools, revision 15'; it depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 9' which was not installed.
```

What do you think might be the problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Running the sdk manage as administrator may solve the problem.

Comment: how can I run the sdk like that? What are the steps? I am still getting used to the environment, and kind of not sure what is meant at times by running it as admin. Should I run my computer as admin? Or how do I start/stop the sdk and restart it as admin?